# Count and write table rows with JS

Tags: javascript, html

i have html table layout from cms. The table can have various rows and from the cms side i can't count it.

But in the table i want to have first column with count number for every row.

I found how i can count all rows number with JS but can't find how to let JS to write numbers in specific column for every row.

my table looks like

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td class="number">...here i want number 1</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="number">...here i want number 2</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you a lot for any advices..

Comment: are you using react, angular, vue or just JavaScript with HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table has `rows` property, you can loop through, and on each row get first `cell` and update it's `textContent` with the `row` with `index + 1`

```js
const table = document.getElementById('mytable');

[...table.rows].forEach((row, i) => {
  row.cells[0].textContent = i + 1;
});
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td class="number">...here i want number 1</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="number">...here i want number 2</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

`rows` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) ( array-like object ), which hasn't the `forEach` function, you need to convert it to an `array` by the spread operator `[...table.rows]`, so you can use `forEach` and loop through.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that this can fail in older browsers, other than this, that’s the correct answer

Comment: thank you. but im not sure what you mean by the dots... i try
[row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')].forEach((row, i) => but it don work..

Comment: `rows` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is array-like object, which hasn't the `forEach` function, you need to convert it to an `array` by the spread operator `[...table.rows]`, so you can use `forEach` and loop through.

Answer (score 1):

You can use js to set a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) with the row number and css (`:after` pseudo selector) to display that. To avoid numbering of possible header rows, find only rows in the table body (demo in snippet).

```js
// rows for the body of the table (so, header row not counted)
document.querySelectorAll(`#mytable tbody tr td:first-child`)
  .forEach((rowNrCell, i) => rowNrCell.dataset.rownumber = i + 1);
```

```css
.number {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.number:after {
  content: '#'attr(data-rownumber);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row</th>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
      <th>col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's the first time I know that It's possible to use `attr` inside CSS, +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a data source coming as an array, or a list, it would look something like this if you're receiving JSON over the network:

```json
{
   users: [
      {
          id: 87126421901,
          name: "Kemal Uyson"
      },
      {
          id: 67212221901,
          name: "Murat Pasa"
      },
      {
          id: 99121924122,
          name: "Yasser Omer"
      },
   ]
}
```

you can use it as it is when saving this response into a variable:

```js
const users = response.data.users // [ the array of users above ]
```

then you can consume it by looping over the array and printing the index of the item in the array as the `number.` of the table row, for instance:

```js
const users = response.data.users // [ the array of users above ]

users.map((row, i)=>{
  // your code here (depends, are you using native JavaScript, React, VUE, Angular ...etc ?)
  // then eventually somewhere here you'll have something like this:
  <td>${i + 1}</td> // i + 1 because i initially equals zero
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just have vanilla js, you can insert a td on tr level.

Use querselectorAll to iterate and do a plus 1 on the index in that loop.

So you have to do createElement and on the tr in the list you call prepend.

See [prepend docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend)